# Is a computational model that can instantly access any storage address and can access any arbitrary number of them at once more powerful then a TM?

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models

This would  be a computational model that would have unbounded space. But with a jump command that can access  and do operations on any finite number of cells at once. Actual calculations would take time, but space could be accessed instantly. If it is not can it at-least solve some problems faster then a Turing machine?

Comment: I suspect you'll be interested in https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22418/755 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/29062/755 and https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/36026/5038 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2666/755.

Comment: @D.W. thanks. One more question. On this model, would there be problems solvable in polynomial time with exponential space? As there is literally no slowdown from accessing memory and it could be freely accessed, and would ideally have some sort of command allowing it to switch to acting like a Turing machine for a bit.

Comment: I believe that was answered here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/148404/755.  For a Turing machine, the space needed is upper-bounded by the running time.  In the RAM model, you can transform any polynomial-time algorithm into one that takes polynomial time and polynomial space.